# How to check if register is empty in MIPS assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips, low-level

So I am writing a tree traversal and my code breaks upon comparing an empty $a0 register with $zero.

I don't know why, but I imagined that since null is just 0, comparing it to zero should not give me an error of

"Attempt to use non-existent memory"
 By the way, I am traversing recursively.

Here is my code snippet

```
        addi    $sp, $sp, -16
        sw      $ra, 12($sp)
        sw      $s0, 8($sp)     # $a0
        sw      $s1, 4($sp)     # $a1
        sw      $s2, 0($sp)     # $a2

pre:
        beq     $a0, $zero, done        # If null done
        move    $s0, $a0                # Preserve $a0
        jalr    $a1                     # Print
        lw      $a0, 4($s0)             # Left Node
        jal     traverse_tree           # Recursive call
        lw      $a0, 8($s0)             # Right Node
        jal     pre                     # Recursive call
        j       done                    # Done

done:
        lw      $ra, 12($sp)
        lw      $s0, 8($sp)
        lw      $s1, 4($sp)
        lw      $s2, 0($sp)
        addi    $sp, $sp, 16
        jr      $ra
```

Comment: Your problem is elsewhere. Verify which instruction causes the problem, but it's probably going to be the `lw` instruction in either the `Left Node` or the `Right Node`.

Comment: But it works up until the point where it reaches a null pointer? If it was something with the lw instruction wouldn't it fail beforehand?

Comment: `beq` does not access memory, so that definitely can't be the faulting instruction. Probably your `$s0` gets corrupted, but not to `NULL` and so the `lw` will fault. use the debugger/simulator to see what happens. Maybe `traverse_tree` that you didn't show doesn't properly preserve `$s0`.

Comment: You were right! I fixed that so far! Thanks, still gotta debug other things.

Comment: Using `jalr` is rare. What's in `$a1`--it's _not_ saved, AFAICT? Does `traverse_tree` trash `$a1`? Also, doing `jal pre` is probably wrong. You probably want `jal traverse_tree` instead. Otherwise, I suspect you'll get infinite stack recursion as you're bypassing the function's stack frame prolog/epilog.

Comment: Hmm, if you use a simulator, that "empty" might happen because you use a0 without setting it first. A simulator might have some "unused"-value.